# Notepad++ RegEx: match IP address ranges that correspond to x.x.x.x/24

Tags: regex

I have a huge list of IP ranges, where each range is split with a hyphen and placed on the new line, and I only need to keep the IPs within the same 3-level range: 50.197.**62**.0-50.197.**62**.255, but not 50.197.62.0-50.197.73.125, etc.
So far couldn't figure how to do this.
I would really appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Additional examples.

Would like to keep:
4.49.119.0-4.49.119.255
12.161.203.64-12.161.203.79
23.25.83.201-23.25.83.201
24.23.113.0-24.23.113.255
38.101.137.0-38.101.137.255
38.107.144.0-38.107.144.255
38.107.146.0-38.107.146.255
50.73.187.0-50.73.187.216

Would like to match with a regex so I can remove them:
64.58.246.0-64.58.247.255
66.212.138.0-66.212.140.255
67.172.21.0-67.172.23.255
67.186.41.128-67.186.50.115
68.235.192.0-68.235.223.255
70.89.104.0-70.89.105.87
71.16.71.96-71.16.72.103
71.60.156.12-71.60.162.255
71.162.15.128-71.162.12.98
72.22.23.0-72.22.24.127

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean here. It looks like you wish to match 50.197.63.0/24, but not some other range, which then excludes that subnet? Could you clarify? Post some examples of IPs that you wish to match and some you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you wish to match any IP address that starts with "50.197.62" you could do this:

```
/50\.197\.62\.\d{1,3}/
```

Usually specifying ranges in IP addresses are done like this: 50.197.62.0/24

It's called CIDR notation, and you can read more about that here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation

EDIT:

After understanding that you wished to match the entire string "ip-ip", it got a lot clearer.

```
/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d{1,3}-\1\d{1,3}/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cO1nQ6/1

EDIT 2:

Reverse:

```
/^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d{1,3}-(?!\1)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/gm
```

This needs the flag `m` for multiline to force the search to go from start of line. I should have used that on the other as well.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eQ5uF1/3

Comment: Thanks, but I have the database of IPs specifically in the way I wrote it in my question, i.e. split with a hyphen. I don't need to re-write them in another way, I just want to write a regular expression to only keep IP ranges with the first three numbers equal. I updated my question with more examples.

Comment: Many thanks, but would you please provide the reverse expression? Because, on the contrary, I need to match those ranges that have different subnets, so I could replace them with nothing.

Comment: Done. This was not what you asked at all, though.

Comment: Thank you. I said that I would like to keep the ranges with the same subnet and remove those with different subnets. Thought I formulated it pretty clear. Sorry if I didn't.

Comment: That's all a matter of perspective. If you have a filter or validation, you need the first one, but if you wish to replace the wrong ones with nothing then you need the second one. I understand how it became wrong, but you should be clearer about what you are trying to actually do in your questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87062/discussion-between-erik-gordon-and-melwil).

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it with BAT command instead of RegEx

```
for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=.-" %a in (iplist.txt) do @if %c EQU %g echo %a.%b.%c.%d-%e.%f.%g.%h>> newiplist.txt
```

Or if you want first 3 blocks to be equal:

```
for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=.-" %a in (iplist.txt) do @if "%a.%b.%c" EQU "%e.%f.%g" echo %a.%b.%c.%d-%e.%f.%g.%h>> newiplist.txt
```

Assuming that iplist.txt is all IPs list and newiplist.txt is new IPs list.

I'd like to notice that you should use single % if run right from shell and double % (%%a, %%b etc) if create batch file.